# How to return a pointer to a slightly modified version of a function?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double square(double x);
double cube(double x);

int main(){
    double (*pArray[2]) (double x) = {square, cube};
    return 0;
}

double square(double x){
    return (x*x);
}

double cube(double x){
    return (x*x*x);
}
```

And now, let's assume* we want a function that in pseudo-code would to something like this (the `+` is not a real addition, mind):

```
functionPointer funcB(y, functionPointer funcA){
    functionPointer funcC = y + &funcA;
    return funcC;
 }
```

such that `funcC` has the same signature as `funcA` and the call `funcC(x)` returns `y + funcA(x)`. How can we achieve this? I can't come up with a way to do it.

---

* Could be useful for something like

```
for(double y = 0; y < 1; y += 0.1){
    for(double x = 0; x <= y; x += 0.1){
         printf("%f\n", funcB(y, pArray[0])(x) );
         printf("%f\n", funcB(y, pArray[1])(x) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `y`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It looks very similar to some kind of callbacks in js which I suspect is influencing the OP's style of question. And anyway, what is this print..? That a new C function? here, using pseudocode and mixing it with C dialects is bound to cause confusion to newcomers to C when they read this question.

Comment: @dbush: doesn't matter, but double. Martin: I wrote that at the very bottom. t0mm13b: Nope, haven't used too much javascript as of yet

Comment: Looks like sort of C++ lambda. Why to use C for this?

Comment: I don't know C++ :D And, well, I don't know much about lambdas either, so I guess I won't achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is called *closure* (a closure can be seen as a anonymous function with some data captured). Unfortunately, you cannot create closures directly<sup>1</sup> in C. The closest you can get is functor objects in C++ (and lambdas, which are a kind of syntax sugar for creating functors), but those cannot be in general converted to function pointers.

You could also emulate closures by introducing additional parameter that is used to maintain state. But that state has to be explicitly managed.

---

<sup>1</sup> In theory, you could allocate some memory, write some machine code there, mark tat memory as executable, and create function pointer to that code. That would however be highly platform-dependent and very complex task.

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, you don't need additional function pointers.  You could just do this:

```
double funcB(double y, functionPointer funcA, double x){
    return y + funcA(x);
} 
...
for(double y = 0; y < 1; y += 0.1){
    for(double x = 0; x <= y; x += 0.1){
         printf("%f\n", funcB(y, pArray[0], x) );
         printf("%f\n", funcB(y, pArray[1], x) );
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if my (actual) code relied on function pointers, i.e. if I needed to pass the return value of funcB, which is a function with one arguement, to some other function, e.g. while doing numerical analysis?